# Fit image from database to a DataGridView Cell

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, bitmap

I am developing a desktop application using a VS-2012 with VB.net.
Here is my code:

```
Dim constring As String = "connection_string"
Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_product", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Using ds As New DataSet()
                sda.Fill(ds)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Image shows the current output:

[image]

How can I display the image fit to the height and width of the Cell?
I changed the row height in design mode (`DataGridView -> RowTemplate -> Height`).
But, don't know how to fit the image to display it properly.

[image]

Comment: it would depend on your autosize value. looks like you have fixed size columns and rows. look here and you will find your answer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.imagelayout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried your solution, but error is: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewImageColumn'.

Comment: Don't post images of code.  We need the text version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your DataGridView is bound to a DataSource (so you possibly have not set Columns properties at Design-Time), you have to verify at Run-Time whether a Cell is hosting a Bitmap object.

One possible way is to subscribe the [CellPainting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting) event and, if the Cell `.ValueType` is of Type Bitmap, re-define the Cell behavior, setting its `.ImageLayout` Property to `Zoom`.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting
    If (e.RowIndex < 0 Or e.ColumnIndex < 0) Then Return

    If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ValueType = GetType(Bitmap) Then
        CType(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex), 
              DataGridViewImageCell).ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom
    End If
End Sub
```

**Update:**
The Image is stored in a SQL DataBase as a Byte Array.
Thus, to identify the image hosting cell, the code had to be changed in:

```
(...)
If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ValueType = GetType(Byte()) Then
(...)
```

Comment: it's remains the same, CellPainting event can not find the "image" cell. and please note that "image" in database is as <Binary data>.

Comment: Check the cell ValueType with the Debugger. When the cell containing the bitmap is parsed, note what ValueType is referenced and change the code accordingly. This is one possibility. Can you specify how the image is stored/referenced in your DataBase?

Comment: (click event of button for image insertion in database) Dim command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_product (item_name, p_image) VALUES(@item_name, @p_image)", con)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
        command.Parameters.Add("@item_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        command.Parameters.Add("@p_image", SqlDbType.Image).Value = ms.ToArray

Comment: it's showing of type Byte. but, neither "byte" is working nor "image". please see the attached image.

Comment: It looks like the Type is `Byte()`.

Comment: I mean `Byte()`, not `Byte`. Have you set `GetType(Byte())`?. If you have, then verify again with the Debugger if it stops there and actually sets that cell `.ImageLayout` to `Zoom`. I tested it and it works anyway.

Comment: at the debug time, I set the debug point at the if condition. but control is not entering into the loop, means control is not going to the statement, even if value type is "byte" (when .ValueType = GetType(Byte)). I can't understand why is this happening?

Comment: You wrote `GetType(Byte)`, not `GetType(Byte())`. It's a byte array Type, not a byte Type.

Comment: oh my god... yeah, its working. I typed Byte instead of Byte(). Thanks sir...thanks for your valuable time.